# GAS: Is there a way to acess the onOpen() function from a library?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use one script in several sheets. To avoid change my script in every sheet every time I change it, I create a library (by the way, is there a better alternative to libraries?). So I call my function in other sheets this way:

```
myFunction(){
return myLibrary.myFunction();
}
```

But, in addition to this `myFunction()`, I have other functions in myLibrary that I'd like to call, that is the `onOpen()` function which I use to put the personalized menus in my sheet. But when I do this:

```
onOpen(){
return myLibrary.onOpen();
}
```

nothing happens. Is there a way to call the `onOpen()` function from my library instead of call the `onOpen()` trigger of my actuall sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to notice when the Library is accessed with onOpen()? The onOpen should relate to the sheet being worked with. I am a little confused.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function onOpen(){
return myLibrary.onOpen();
}` ?

Comment: No, @JacobFlatter. I'm trying to access the myLibrary.onOpen() to put the menus of myLibrary script.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this thread where this issue has been discussed in great detail

[Spreadsheet onOpen menu from a Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842441/spreadsheet-onopen-menu-from-a-library)

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work. 
Check the script library for any errors or duplicate functions. If it is a small script, just comment out everything but the onOpen function.

I had the same issue, it turned out to be an issue with the script in the library.

If you are using the function to add menu items, these functions also need to be in the script related to the spreadsheet. The menu will not execute any functions in the library.