# How to change a "bound" Script to a "Standalone" script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets script that's bound to a specific doc. Basically it takes the results of certain cells, then it used these values in doc.

I have multiple Sheets I'd like to "attach" to this script. All the other Sheets have the exact same tabs and cell names, etc.

Is there a way to turn that bound script to a standalone script, then attach them to the other Sheets?

Comment: You'll always have to define what sheet you're working in. Either take the active sheet (`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`) or define a specific sheet (`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");`). If this is not what you're looking for, consider to clarify your question.

Comment: You can use either a library or an add-on to accomplish what you want to do.  In either case, there needs to be some set up or installation, unless you are in a domain and can deploy the add-on to all users in the domain.

Comment: You can use library or an add-on as Sandy Good said. But if you are required to create the project into a Spreadsheet as a bound script, how about using Google Apps Script API? 1. Retrieve the project from the existing Spreadsheet using [``projects.get``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/get). 2. Create the retrieved project into other Spreadsheet as a bound script using [``projects.create``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You cannot unbind a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound):

> The file a bound script is attached to is referred to as a "container". Bound scripts generally behave like standalone scripts except that they do not appear in Google Drive, they cannot be detached from the file they are bound to, and they gain a few special privileges over the parent file.

To use the functionality you've created, you'll want to export the bound script as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) and import it in the other spreadsheets' script editors. [You may also have to do some tweaks to get any UI alterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842441/spreadsheet-onopen-menu-from-a-library)

Note that an installed library will not automatically update the used version, so if you make changes to your library source and save a new version, you'll have to go through all the spreadsheets that reference it and update the library version.

---

The alternative to a library is to go through the process to [publish your script as an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish). This will let you redeploy your changes without needing to go through every single spreadsheet.