# Google Sheets - Menu Click Function in Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have gsheet menu item as follows, where the executing function resides in library "rm".

```
ui.createMenu('Test').addItem('Test-Lib', 'rm.test');
```

I have tested this and it works. However, I was not able to find any documentation on this. So my question is; **is this a supported feature** which I can rely on going forward?

The use case here is: I will be distributing copies of the same gsheet to different clients, so having a single code repository helps updating all clients at the same time. -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spreadsheet onOpen menu from a Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842441/spreadsheet-onopen-menu-from-a-library)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Someone else has figured out it works as I said. But the question posed different.

Comment: If the answer is "the same", the questions are considered duplicates. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Hmmm. Answer has to be different. I'm looking for documentation, indicating if this feature is officially supported, as there does not seem the be any documentation.
This is fundamentally different from the linked question.

Comment: Question asking for external resources are considered off-topic, actually there is a specific close as off-topic reason for those questions "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: By the other hand, have you considered to publish your code as an add-on instead of a library?

Comment: OK got it, thanks. Question is too broad/open. I was hoping there might be a gsheets developer who could give specific info, as I could not find any in my searching.

Comment: Try https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769